# Newlfm class and indentation

Tags: indentation, letters, newlfm

I am trying to write cover letter using Latex, I found out about [`newlfm`](http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/newlfm/manual.pdf) class, I almost got what I wanted, but I can't make him indent any paragraphs.

What I want is to get first line of every paragraph indented. Is it possible to achieve something like that using this class?

Comment: How about `\setlength\parindent{5pt}` (Place this in the preamble.)? You can change the paragraph indentation with this for the entire document.

Comment: Easiest solutions are the best it seems :). Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to modify the paragraph indentation command `\parindent` with `\setlength\parindent{length}`. For example:

```
\documentclass{newlfm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength\parindent{1cm}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3] 
\end{document}
```

See result:

[image]