# Five questions to the newlfm document class

Tags: letters, newlfm

I have fives smaller issue with the `newlfm` documentclass.

1. How can I place the `\addrfrom{}` below the name at the bottom of my letter?
2. How can O get the `\regarding{}` command to aling on `\\` like the `\cclist{}` command?
3. Is there a *proper* way to space the “Dear … “ from the meta-information above?
4. How do I add page numbers?
5. How do I create indentation on all paragraphs?

Here MWE (screenshot below)

```
\documentclass[sigleft]{newlfm}

\newlfmP{Headlinewd=0pt,Footlinewd=0pt}

\setlength\parindent{1cm} % to get indentation thanks to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58976/71924

\namefrom{Sherlock Holmes}
\addrfrom{%
    221B Baker Street\\
    London, UK
}

\addrto{%
    Basil of Baker Street\\
    221 Baker Street\\
    London, UK
}

\regarding{Placement of \emph{from address},\\ 
\emph{alignment of ``regarding:''},\\
\emph{spacing},\\
\emph{page numbers}, and\\
\emph{indent on all pargraphs} in the newlfm class}

\dateset{\today}

\greetto{Dear  Adrien Nunemaker,}

\closeline{Sincerely,}


\cclist{Verdell Blann\\
Rebecka Burton\\
Brooks Linke\\
Roseann Mccallum\\
Johnie Amen \\
}

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
I am writing \ldots

The \TeX enige is.

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

[image: bam!]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to use a letter-related class to set letters. The changes you seek go against the rigid enforcement that is associated with a class. So, break from it and set it in `article`. There is no shame in this, and it allows you *extreme* freedom to place content where you want them to go:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\hfill\today

\medskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  Basil of Baker Street \\
  221 Baker Street \\
  London, UK
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\noindent
Regarding: \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
  Placement of \emph{from address}, \\
  \emph{alignment of ``regarding:''}, \\
  \emph{spacing}, \\
  \emph{page numbers}, and \\
  \emph{indent on all pargraphs} in the \texttt{newlfm} class
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\noindent
Dear Adrien Nunemaker,

\bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vel porttitor sapien. 
Ut porttitor orci ipsum, vitae congue augue elementum a. Proin consectetur semper 
tortor, id pharetra turpis pellentesque nec. Praesent urna nisl, finibus quis laoreet 
sit amet, dictum nec lorem. Mauris consectetur sem luctus dolor mollis, in consectetur 
eros faucibus. Vivamus cursus volutpat tellus id laoreet. Vestibulum consectetur sem 
quis erat lobortis, et pretium justo sodales.

\noindent
Sincerely,

\bigskip\bigskip

\noindent
Sherlock Holmes

\medskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  221B Baker Street \\
  London, UK
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\noindent
cc: \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
  Verdell Blann \\
  Rebecka Burton \\
  Brooks Linke \\
  Roseann Mccallum \\
  Johnie Amen
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Specifically to your questions:

1. Since I'm using `article`, there is no restrict in terms of placement of content. Move to where you want them to appear, and they will.
2. Use a `[t]`op-aligned `tabular` to set such structured content.
3. I've made liberal use of `\bigskip`, but there is no *proper* way. It depends on what you think looks good (subjective).
4. This comes default with the `plain` page style when using `article`.
5. This comes default with `article`. I've negated it using `\noindent` wherever needed.

Sure you *can* achieve the above output using [`newlfm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm), but why go through the trouble of adjusting internals of the class when it's really not necessary.

Comment: I initially broke away from the `letter` class to the `newlfm` class because the former was to rigid, but I guess I should simply do it all in `article` with the freedom it provides. I appreciate your response!